# Rate button does not exit to the App Store when tapped

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I submitted app to the App Store that has rate button implemented like this:

```
UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(NSURL(string : "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idxxxxx")! as URL)
```

They rejected my app saying that the rate button did not exit to the App Store when tapped. They reviewed the app on iPad and iPhone running iOS 10.1 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.

I can only test my app on simulator so I can't check if rate button is working or not.

What is the correct way to open app in App Store?

Comment: JAL already give the right answer. I just want to add that you can redirect the user directly to your apps review page with this link: `http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=<YOUR APP ID>&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=2&type=Purple+Software&mt=8`. Don't forget to put your `APP ID` instead of the placeholder `<YOUR APP ID>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`canOpenURL` only checks if the URL can be opened.  In your case, you need to use `openURL` to actually open the URL:

```
let url = URL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idxxxxx")!

if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Review the documentation for [`canOpenURL:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl) and [`openURL:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-open).